# Entrancethemetransition delay after the third item for Windows 10 Anniversary version

Tags: xaml, animation, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am using the `Entrancethemetransition`  to animate several buttons. After updating my OS to Windows 10 Anniversary as well as Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, I noticed a peculiar behaviour of the animation.

There is a slight delay (nearly 1 second) after the third item animation. This occurs in both Mobile and Desktop.

```
<StackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
    <TransitionCollection>
        <EntranceThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="1000" IsStaggeringEnabled="True"/>
    </TransitionCollection>
</StackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
```

Is this a bug or do I have to do the animation differently?

**UPDATE**

Here's a code snippet to reproduce this behaviour. Noticed the slight delay starting from the 4th button.

```
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <StackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="2000" IsStaggeringEnabled="True"/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </StackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
    <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button 1" Margin="12" />
    <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Button 2" Margin="12"/>
    <Button x:Name="button3" Content="Button 3" Margin="12"/>
    <Button x:Name="button4" Content="Button 4" Margin="12"/>
    <Button x:Name="button5" Content="Button 5" Margin="12"/>
    <Button x:Name="button6" Content="Button 6" Margin="12"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can see your issue on Win10 RS1 and this seems like a unknown issue we have logged, thank you for reporting.

The related team is investigating it, you can move forward if it doesn't affect the experience seriously:)